# htaccess dynamic subdomain rewriting

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I promise I have been looking for hours for the answer here, but it's still not working. Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

This creates an infinite loop because line two is not matching correctly. However, if I replace `%1` in line two with `www` and go to `www.example.com`, it works fine. Obviously it no longer works for the other subdomains, but the fact that when I explicitly enter `www` in line two instead of letting `%1` take care of it is strange, because I know the value of `%1` is `www`.

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:
I have a domain "example.com". In the root directory there are several subdirectories, let's say "dev", "test" and "www". Higher up in my htaccess file I have a rule that forces the domain to redirect to "www.example.com" if the subdomain is empty (example.com), w (w.example.com), or ww (ww.example.com), anything else is left alone (dev.example.com, test.example.com). Now this part of the file is supposed to rewrite the request to the correct subdirectory based on the subdomain. So, a request like "dev.example.com/something.jpg" gets rewritten (not redirected) to "dev.example.com/dev/something.jpg".

The plan here is to be able to create a development and testing environments on the server, without having to recreate an environment on my home server, making sure all the server settings are exactly the same. Also, it could do anything else I wanted it to do I suppose, but that's the immediate need.

Comment: Can You tell us what do You want to achieve ?

Comment: Of course, sorry. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use a backreference variable in the match expression of a `RewriteCond`. This is OK:

```
# ----------V
RewriteCond %1 <regex>
```

But this is not:

```
# -------------------------V
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %1
```

Something you could do if you needed to do a match like this is use match backreference `\1` to access a match from within the same regular expression. You can then put the `%1` back reference in the same left side parameter of `RewriteCond` and use `\1` to match against it. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)[^:]*:\1 [NC]
```

So the `%{REQUEST_URI}:%1` bit could look something like this: `/foo:subdomain`, and `^/([^/]+)[^:]*:\1` won't match because the expression is looking for **foo** after the ":" (`\1` = "foo"). So the rule gets applied and the URI is now `/subdomain/foo`, and the second time around, `%{REQUEST_URI}:%1` becomes `/subdomain/foo:subdomain`, this time the regular expression matches because `\1` = "subdomain" and the `!` makes it so the rule *doesn't* get applied.

Comment: It seems to be doing exactly what I want it to do. Now I just need to study it a bit to make sure I understand what is taking place. I guess I was just viewing `%1` as a variable from the previous `RewriteCond` that could be used anywhere. Thanks so much for your prompt help!

Comment: Ok, I've found a little quirk. With this line (which otherwise works great), if you go to `www.example.com/water`, it will rewrite to `www.example.com/water`, not `www.example.com/www/water`. It's matching the first letter of the subdomain with the first letter of the `%{REQUEST_URI}`, causing it not to rewrite. The same thing happens with a subdomain like "dev", and an address like `dev.example.com/dapper`. The solution I've come up with is a lookahead as follows: `!^/([^/]+)(?=/)[^:]*:\1`. If there is a more concise method here, I'd love to hear it. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Patrick Don't think there's a more concise method, updating the regex with lookahead is a fine solution