# apache mod rewrite for subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

On my webserver, I have one website located at `example.com/site` (in `/var/www/site`).

I want it to be accessed through `site.example.com`, and I'm aware I need to use mod-rewrite to enable this.

Is there a concise snippet I can use to do this? I need to make it extensible so other sites can be accessed this way as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simon's answer could go in a .htaccess file within the main root of your site.

Comment: i.e., in /var/www or in /var/www/site ?

Comment: I would assume /var/www/site (you can test this by just putting rubbish into the .htaccess and you should get a 500 error when browsing to the site).

Comment: Ok, I will try this shortly. THanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is a matter of one specific subdomain: `site`, then you should explicitly rewrite just that one subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

The second condition prevents an internal rewrite loop and making your URI look like `/site/site/site/site/site/site/` etc...

This would go in your .htaccess file in your document root, `/var/www/`

If you really want to arbitrarily redirect any subdomain, you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%1 !^/([^/]+)[^:]*:\1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Here, the second condition serves the same purpose, it tries to make sure the request URI doesn't start with the subdomain match from the host. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508430/851273 for a better explanation.

Comment: I tried the first approach with the .htaccess in the /var/www. But so far site.example.com goes straight to the example.com root...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to configure your server to accept any subdomain for your domain example.com and redirect it to your virtual host that as well has to accept any subdomain. After that, you can use the following rule to rewrite that subdomain internally to a folder with the same name:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, about the first part, what would that involve?

Comment: Also, where does this snippet go?

Comment: Those rules will cause an internal rewrite loop

Comment: I'll mean that you can set this Rewrite script insite your VirtualHost. And if you want to point any sub-domain into this VirtualHost you can set the ServerAlias to *.domain.tld